# SharePoint extranet security

Tags: security, sharepoint

I'm trying to set up our SharePoint site so that it can be accessed by external users.  I've set up my firewall to only allow HTTPS connections to it and everything works fine except when you click to open a folder in a document library, the link points to http://server/folder instead of https://server/folder.  Does anyone know if there's a way to make the folder links point to https instead of http?

Comment: Er... are you interested in some of the other serious security considerations of SharePoint that you might want to consider before exposing it to outside parties?

Comment: I'm thinking that you neeed to set up alternate access mappings, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - just needed to set up the alternate access mappings by extending the web application - thanks joeqwerty!   I've configured my firewall so that only certain IP's will be able to access the site, but does anyone have any other insight for SharePoint security that I should be thinking about (apart from what I've done already)?